# Is it bad practice to autosubmit a form with javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit

My development department is in an argument about autosubmitting a form with javascript when all elements are filled in. We've got a form with 2 select-elements, which we currently submit is both are selected.

What are some good pro and con arguments for autosubmitting a form with javascript? The only real argument we've came up with so far is that the user can't easily correct it's selection if the form is autosubmitted: he'll have to go back to the previous page where the form is located. However, if the user does fill in the form correctly, it might save him some time (half a second maybe, but still).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is unexpected behaviour. Selections (confusing exceptions aside) do not submit forms. Clicking a submit button submits forms.

Answer (score 2):

Autosubmiting plays well when you load results dynamically into the current page, but still you should not rely on this. About your case - definitely no.

Answer (score 0):

To "fix" the argument you mentioned (which is indeed good one) you can add `confirm` dialog before auto submitting:

```
if (confirm('Are the values correct?'))
   myForm.submit();
```

Apart of that, nothing wrong in my opinion in auto submitting.

Comment: I don't mean to offend you, but in my opinion that's even worse than autosubmitting a form with incorrect values. I don't ever want the user to see a javascript alert.

Comment: None taken. That's just my advice to let the user correct value if it's wrong - you don't have to use it.